# Unable to move child elements in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout

I am using Android Studio GUI Editor. After taking Constraintlayout as root element, added Button to layout. soon it jumps to top left corner. I am unable to move that button to center of layout. any help please.

here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: here GUI is]

Comment: According to the xml you provided, the button is already centered. I'd advise you to not use the GUI editor. Instead edit the xml by hand and see it in the preview on the right

Comment: can you post your gradle?